# Solving $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n}{e^nn!}$

Tags: limits

I was solving a convergence of a series and this limit popped up:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n}{e^nn!}$$

I needed this limit to be $0$ and it is in fact (according to WolframAlpha), but I just don't see how to get the result.

Comment: Have a look at the [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: Stirling's approximation or some integral approximation are the easiest ways to go. However, it is still possible to prove it by just using induction and some clever manipulations (just see below).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n$ by Stirling's approximation, we have

$$\frac{n^n}{e^nn!} = \frac{(n/e)^n}{n!} \sim \frac{(n/e)^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}} \to 0.$$

Comment: Thanks, I knew there must be some trick - but I forgot about Stirling :-)

Answer (score 3):

Almost as good: write the expression as 
$$
L = e^{n \log n - n - \log n!} = e^{n \log n -n -\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k} 
$$
and use the bounds on the sum:
$$
\int_{1}^{n} \log x dx < \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k < \int_{1}^{n+1} \log x dx
$$
to get the same result without Stirling.

Answer (score 3):

The ratio of two consecutive values is
$$
\left.\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{e^{n+1}(n+1)!}\middle/\frac{n^n}{e^nn!}\right.=\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}{e}\tag{1}
$$
Taking the log of $(1)$ gives
$$
n\left(\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)-1
=-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\tag{2}
$$
Since
$$
\int_1^{n+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\le1+\int_1^n\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\tag{3}
$$
we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\log(n)+O(1)\tag{4}
$$
Therefore, summing $(2)$ using $(4)$ yields
$$
\log\left(\frac{n^n}{e^nn!}\right)=-\frac12\log(n)+O(1)\tag{5}
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\frac{n^n}{e^nn!}\le\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}\tag{6}
$$
The limit sought is therefore, $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right) = n, $$
hence:
$$ n! = \prod_{m=2}^{n} m = \prod_{m=2}^{n}\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{n-k}=\frac{n^n}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k}$$
and:
$$\frac{n^n}{n!}=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k}.\tag{1}$$
Since the sequence defined by:
$$ a_k = \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k+\frac{1}{3}} $$
is increasing towards $e$, from $(1)$ it follows that:
$$ \frac{n^{n+\frac{1}{3}}}{n!}=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k \leq e^{n-1}\tag{2} $$
hence:
$$ \frac{n^n}{n!e^n}\leq\frac{1}{e\sqrt[3]{n}},\tag{3}$$
proving our claim.

Comment: How do we show that $\left(1+\frac1k\right)^{k+\frac13}$ is increasing? This might be questioned since $\left(1+\frac1k\right)^{k+\frac12}$ is decreasing.